# when building an ionic app files and folders starting with "._" are created until error

Tags: ios, macos, build, ionic-framework, npm

I have a strange problem. I develop an app using Ionic on a samba network drive.
I develop on a windows machine and run all the command lines regarding Android development. I switch to a Mac to be able to build for iOS.

All went fine and as expected the last couple of days. Today I edited some HTML, JS and CSS files - just some minor improvements. I built the app for android on the windows machine (plus using jarsigner and zipalign - only if that should matter).
On the Mac I had troubles. Suddenly I get errors when trying to run `ionic build --release ios` (as I already did successfully the last couple days).

[image]

The executed script creates files and folders starting with "**._**" which were never created before and are already existing without it. This results at some point in an ENOENT (no such file or directory) aborting everything.

I don't get it. I already de-/re-installed node, npm, cordova and ionic. But nothing helped.

I would love to support you guys with additional error messages or logs, but due to I'm fairly new to mobile development (and using a Mac), I don't know what information would be helpful and what not.
Sp please tell me any information you need and I'll be happy to supply them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally solved my own problem. I just "removed" the ***platforms*** directory (by renaming it) and re-added the platform using the command `cordova platform add ios`.

After that I could build my app as it did before. Don't know why or what actually triggered this behavior, but at least I'm able to proceed.

If somebody knows how to prevent that from happening again (so that I don't loose all the project settings I configured in Xcode), I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, too - I found this bug in the Cordova issues:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5644

> I found out that Xcode created the file PROJECT_PATH/platforms/ios/._APPNAME.xcodeproject. I deleted this file and "cordova prepared ios" was working again.

...

> It should ignore files starting with ._ as they are hidden system
>   files used by osx to store infos about a file